# Cleaning and Extracting JSON From Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with the following structure:

```
id    year  name        homepage        
238   2022  Adventure  {'keywords': 'en', 'genres':[{"revenue": 1463, "name": "culture clash"}], 'runtime': 150, 'vote_average': 7}
```

But what I need is this structure

```
   id    year   name        keywords    revenue     name               runtime vote_average
   238   2022  Adventure     en         1460        culture clash      150     7
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to `json_normalize` "homepage" column and `join` it back to `df`. You can pass meta and the record path directly into `json_normalize` as parameters:

```
out = (df.join(pd.json_normalize(df['homepage'], record_path='genres', 
                                 meta=['keywords', 'runtime', 'vote_average']), 
               lsuffix='', rsuffix='_genres')
       .drop(columns='homepage'))
```

Output:

```
    id  year       name keywords  revenue    name_genres runtime vote_average
0  238  2022  Adventure       en     1463  culture clash     150            7
```